# Joomla - Change main menu

Tags: joomla, joomla-template

Im newbie to Joomla. How do I change the main menu like screen below to my customize menu?

[Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKTlE.png)

Comment: you'd better provide a link on this test page if possible, or show html-code of the page and php-code of template (in templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/index.php) - so we could understand which module should be changed/customised

Comment: the css file for Joomla templates is usually template.css or menu.css
I would suggest using Firebug or Inspecting the element to find the css file name and line number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own custom menu from the backend. Login to your administrator panel.

```
Menus->Menu Manager->Add New Manager
```

Enter the menu details and you will be able to see it in the drop down. Select menu type items and assign articles, contact etc to your newly created menu.

Now under `Extensions` tab click on `Module Manager` . Now manage your custom menu to the position you want it to display. Like if you want to display your `custom menu` as main menu then go to main menu and assign your menu to it under basic options and the position you want it to display.

Following are the links where you can find more help-

- [Joomla code help](http://docs.joomla.org/Developers)
- [Joomla docs](http://docs.joomla.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Not clear from your question that what you need to do but as per your menu image i will describe my answers.

1. If you need to change the position of menu then go to backend extension->Module Manager->select main menu and change position of main menu.

Also same you can change your custom menu positions.

2. If you need to change main menu and set custom menu instead of main menu then you need to change menu position and set position of custom menu from module manager.

Menu items will be added from the menus->select menu->add new menu items.

3. Not clear from your question that what you need to do but as per your menu image I will explain my answer below -

if you want to main menu to be a drop-down menu then you can use some free menu extension module of joomla like  JB DropDown Menu or CK Megamenu, dropdown menu.